# Trash removes emails automatically

Tags: trash

I have Mozilla Thunderbird and each morning when I TURN ON COMPUTER it automatically removes some trash. I don't want this, I would rather do it manually. can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option named "Empty Trash on Exit" in Thunderbird. Maybe this setting is turned on.

Check account settings by right clicking on your account and going to  "Settings...".

There, you can navigate to "Server settings". There should be a text box below the caption "Message Storage" named "Empty trash on exit". Make sure this is not checked.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you but its none of these

Comment: If you are using IMAP for your mailbox it might be so that your mailprovider does this for you?